# a devotional sentence that uses all letters

Tags: krishna, radha

There are a few common sentences used to practice keyboard skills, like

> The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog

or

> The five boxing wizards jump quickly

I wonder if there would be a similar sentence with Radhe Shyam (Radha-Shyamasundara)
or any other names of Radha and Krishna.

This is not opinion based. Just it is a question that can have many answers. I just need ONE sentence with all the letters to practice typewriting and I would love to have something devotional to practice with.

That's all.
Very simple, but at the same time not easy, otherwise I would have done it already.

Comment: shiva shankar ishwar fanishwar gangadhar kedarnath badrinath umashankar jay parameshwar chandrashekhar omkareshwar lingaraja aqul laxmikant  this one uses all but z

Comment: nice. z is not a sanskrit letter so it's ok @AdityaDwivedi

Comment: Any one can make sentence with all the letters in one sloka.. Raghavendra swaigal had writen one padya which longest sentence in sanskrit i dont whether it had all the letters.. the granta name pratha sankalpa gadya

Comment: This question is interesting , but opinion based.

Comment: Other than f: shaanta-kaaram bhujzaga-shayanam padma-naabham suresham,
vishwa-dhaaram gagana-sadrisham megha-varanam shubhaangam.
laxmi-kaantam kamala-nayanam yogi-bhi-dhyaana-agamyam,
vande vishnum bhava-bhaya-haram sarva-locaiqa-naatham.. (z, c, x, w and q also fitted but i think still it'll have correct pronunciation)..